# How to achieve this format in swift?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, swift2

I want to pass a parameter in my POST method. This is the valid parameter to be sent.

```
{
            "feedback" : "Sample Feedback",
            "orderId" : 1240,
            "ratings" :     [
            {
            "rateType" : 1,
            "rating" : 3
            },
            {
            "rateType" : 2,
            "rating": 4
            }
            ],
            "sellerId" : 598,
            "title" : "Sample title"
    }
```

I am using this(below) to achieve that format(above) but the server returns **invalid feedback**. Please help me if I'm missing something or doing wrong to achieve the format above.

```
let parameter: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "sellerId": self.sellerId,
        "orderId": self.orderId,
        "title": "Seller Feedback",
        "feedback": "Sample Feedback",
        "ratings": [[
            "rateType": 1,
            "rating": self.rate1
            ], [
                "rateType": 2,
                "rating": self.rate2
            ]]
    ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is invalid `feedback`? Probably error is the `ratings` phase formatting, and server return wrong error position.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not ordered. you'll have to implement your own ordered dictionary or use a struct. here is one from http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/

```
struct OrderedDictionary<Tk: Hashable, Tv> {
    /* ... vars and init ... */

    subscript(key: Tk) -> Tv? {
        get {
            return self.values[key]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if newValue == nil {
                self.values.removeValueForKey(key)
                self.keys.filter {$0 != key}
                return
            }

            let oldValue = self.values.updateValue(newValue!, forKey: key)
            if oldValue == nil {
                self.keys.append(key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```